Core-Bluetooth Specific Peripheral connection
I want to use an ESP32 with a custom iOS app to control a couple of servo motors over BLE. I can't however figure out how to connect to a specific device from within CoreBluetooth. Could anybody show me a demo of how this is done, with a specific device identifier or anything?
I tried looking through the CoreBluetooth documentation, but I didn't find it very easy to understand or find what I wanted.

It isn't possible to connect directly to some peripheral based on an identifier. First you need to scan for peripherals to discover them. You can scan for peripherals that are advertising a particular gatt service and you can have your ESP32 code advertise that service (you can create your own random, UUiD for the service). Once you have discovered the peripheral you have an identifier that you can use for future connections,  but this identifier is unique for the combination of your peripheral and the discovering iOS device.

There are many examples on github.com, like https://github.com/Pluto-Y/Swift-LightBlue. Specifically, take a look at the file BluetoothManager.swift for the basics.
